# Lifetime of the transformer in a high voltage power source

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I am solving a problem with the **design of a high voltage power source**. The **problem is** related to the **lifetime of the transformer** (1 primary + 2 secondary windings). The power supply has 50-100VDC at its input and I need 4000-9000VDC. This power supply has to charge output capacitors to this voltage and it's driven by MCU.

### Power supply topology:

Power source topology can be seen from the **attached image**. PWM is used to supply current to the primary winding (50-100VDC). There are voltage multipliers on the secondary windings of the transformer (stacking topology). We have two secondary windings, i.e. two multipliers and their outputs are connected in parallel. It's simple.

[image]

### Problem + question:

The whole source works perfectly, but it has a short life. The transformer stops transferring power from the primary to the secondary winding after a while. The service life is in the order of tens of hours. It is always necessary to replace the transformer.

**Question:** what problem can the given solution be? Why does the transformer get destroyed?

#### Transformer parameters:

Transformer is custom designed and made by external supplier with the following parameters:

- 5000V peak isolation from primary to secondary winding;
- 5000V peak isolation between secondary windings;
- transformer output: 2.2kV RMS, 180mA/winding
- primary inductance 35uH
- transformer ratio: 9:300 (prim:sec)
  [image]

#### Description of the behavior of a faulty transformer:

A damaged transformer can be recognized as follows:

- has a hissing sound when in operation
- the output of the entire source is low
- it is not a gradual change, it happens suddenly
- the inductance remains the same, winding resistances are also the same, no windings are not shorted together
- in normal (working)operation, I measured a maximum of +2400V and -2400V directly on the secondary winding

---

### EDIT: Additional information:

The power supply needs about 20ms to charge the load from 0 to 8kV (100pF load, 10MOhms self-discharge resistor). The load is than quickly discharged and this repeats over and over (40Hz).
Current in to primary winding is limited by the hardware to 50A peak.
Transformer is during continuous operation cold (after 15 minutes of operation has the surface still ambient temperature).

It's an interesting idea with ozone. We didn't feel anything. But the truth is that the earlier prototype with a smaller transformer also failed many times and **arcing** was on one piece visible ([see the link with video](https://streamable.com/3lwc46)). The previous smaller transformer differed from the current one by half the nominal secondary voltage (1100V). Overall, the small and current transformer behave the same (have the same failure)

**Primary driving method**: valley switching technique. Feedback is via a galvanically isolated amplifier (feedback from the final output of the source). The amplifier is Texas Inst. AMC1301.

**Components in the multiplier:**

- diodes: GP02-40-E3/54 (4000Vr, If = 250mA, I peak = 15A), 1 diode in the schematic = 4 diodes connected in parallel on the PCB
- capacitors: Kemet PHE450XB4100JB04R17 (1nF, 3000VDC)

**More about used transformer:**

- it should be varnished by the producer
- core is used tpw33 ssp-95
- wires comings out of the transformer have spaghetti tubing
- I'm unable to tell how thick the insulation is between the windings; I only have information that it is 3Ts, type PF-3001 by Jingjiang Yahua Pressure Sensitive Glue Co.,Ltd
- we operate the transformer normally mounted on the PCB, it is not immersed in oil or any other substance
  [image]
  [image]

Unfortunately, I don't have an insulation tester.

Comment: It is **rather awkward** to read some of **your post** due to unusual **application** of bold.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the windings with an insulation tester? Sounds like a breakdown of some sort.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing transformers intended for high voltages where sections of the HV winding are separated by raised bits of insulation, a bit like those raised bits of insulator you see on suspended HV lines. So wind, wind, wind, over the bump, wind, wind, wind, over the bump, etc. ICBW. Is your transformer constructed like that? Have you checked for evidence of tracking along surfaces? (I am not a qualified electrical engineer.)

Comment: Can you operate it in complete darkness and look for arcing?

Comment: check for the smell of ozone, which would indicate that the transformer is arcing ... it can be described as a metallic smell

Comment: What capacitance value are the output capacitors? How long do you permit to charge from from 0 volts? What transformer core are you using? What primary driving method do you use? What diodes do you use in your multiplier? Ditto the multiplier capacitors. What thickness of insulation between windings do you use? I'd be considering at least 1mm thickness.

Comment: I'd also be curious of what the winding(s) and core temperatures are?

Comment: When internal winding wires come out to the edge of the bobbin, are they in spaghetti tubing to space them from adjacent wiring?   Have you tried an impregnation (or just dunking the transformer in some mineral oil) to ensure that you aren't getting corrosive effect from ozone due to corona in air?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your posts. I will try to answer all questions.

I have added additional information to the introductory post.